# Celery, periodic task execution, with concurrency

Tags: python, django, celery

I would like to launch a periodic task every second but only if the previous task ended (db polling to send task to celery). 
In the Celery documentation they are using the Django cache to make a lock.

I tried to use the example:

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import

import datetime
import time

from celery import shared_task

from django.core.cache import cache
LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 5

@shared_task
def periodic():

    acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add('lock_id', 'true', LOCK_EXPIRE)
    release_lock = lambda: cache.delete('lock_id')

    a = acquire_lock()
    if a:
        try:
            time.sleep(10)
            print a, 'Hello ', datetime.datetime.now()
        finally:
            release_lock()
    else:
        print 'Ignore'
```

with the following configuration:

```python
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
        'periodic_task': {
            'task': 'app_task_management.tasks.periodic',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        },
    },
)
```

But in the console, I never see the `Ignore` message and I have `Hello` every second. It seems that the lock is not working fine.

I launch the periodic task with:

```sh
celeryd -B -A my_app
```

and the worker with:

```sh
celery worker -A my_app -l info
```

Could you please correct my misunderstanding?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps Celery Workers are running different processes and so locks do not apply?

Comment: what kind of cache are you using?

Comment: @fixmycode: CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Django Cache Framework documentation about [local-memory cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching):

> Note that each process will have its own private cache instance, which
>   means no cross-process caching is possible.

So basically your workers are each dealing with their own cache. If you need a low resource cost cache backend I would recommend File Based Cache or Database Cache, both allow cross-process.

Comment: Thank you, this explains why it is not working well. I am quite embarrassed as the filebased or database cache will be costly for a db polling. The best solution will be memcache but this implies a new daemon. Is there a way to produce a lock system with celery and rabbitmq queue?

Comment: no that I know of. Maybe you could pull it off using Redis, and also using Redis as the broker for Celery instead of RabbitMQ. Redis supports locking keys natively.